# How to perform pattern recognition across parameters and interpolate it using Python?

Tags: python, neural-network, interpolation, pattern-recognition

Let's say there is a simple sinusoidal data according to a parameter.

For a parameter `a = [1, 2, 3, ..., 18, 19, 20]`,

2-D temporal data exists where,

`y(a, t) = a*sin(a*t + a)`           (t=time)

So, amplitude, frequency, and phase of the 2-D data, `y(a,t)` changes according to a parameter `a`.

I want to build a network that is capable of recognizing the pattern and interpolate data `y(a,t)` according to the parameter `a`.
For instance, I would like to get `y(a=10.5, t)`.

I've tried LSTMs (seq2seq, autoencoder, etc) but had no luck. From my research so far, it looks like Python/TensorFlow does not have modules that can handle both interpolation of a parameter and pattern recognition.

Comment: Well I can try out few experiments if you can provide some more detail about what exactly you are trying to accomplish. And also how you generate training data.

Comment: @Kumar Thank you for the comment. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1caJxN6N2VXbVBoHqaXm8JB0QwJ7BBGIK/view?usp=sharing
This is the data I'm working on. The x-axis is the parameter and y-axis is the time. So what I'm trying to do is get data strands between parameters. Specifically, I would like to get temporal data of variable 2.5 (the middle point between 2 and 3 on the x-axis).

Comment: @Kumar I know that I will be needing more data points of parameter but unfortunately, this is a part of CFD dataset and it takes very long for me to acquire more data which I'm still working on. If you could point me the direction I should be heading to, it would be more than enough.

Comment: @Kumar If the above dataset is not enough, this dataset could be better https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U3ShxlYV9Mi4XM0vcDCltmlGua-wCDSG/view?usp=sharing
It contains 20 parameters and are just simple sinusoidal response. In case my above explanation is not enough, I would like to get time series data in between the parameters. For this example, time series data of parameter = 10.5.

Comment: Could you be specific about what is the input parameters and what is target

Comment: @Kumar So there are two input parameters, time and 'a'. The time is shown as a set of rows on the .csv files and 'a' is shown as the columns.The data consists as a function of time which are dependent on the parameter 'a'.The target is to get time dependent data with arbitrary parameter `a`, thus recognize the pattern of parameter and interpolate it on parameter 'a'.

Comment: Could you please rearrange the above training and test data column wise as parameters and target (three columns only and two for input parameter and third for target) so that it is easy to understand. And then share it

Comment: I'm sorry if I have made any confusion.
This is the new dataset and .ppt file that explains what I'm trying to do. Thank you for your help https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bm-RYbjNhNAGaZyVBs9wn0WbC3rXrjiE/view?usp=sharing